# Add JavaScript Array of Object properties values to get a total count number

Tags: javascript

Based on a JavaScript array of objects like this one below, is it possible to add the number values on the count property of all the items together and store in a variable as a total count without iterating over the array?

```
var category_names_array = [
  {name: 'cat1', count: 13},
  {name: 'cat2', count: 23},
  {name: 'cat3', count: 33}
];
```

Comment: Use `.reduce()`. Though that _is_ iterating over the array, albeit not explicitly.

Comment: Define "iterating".

Comment: Another way: `eval(array.map(x=>x.count).join\`+\`)`

Comment: @Guedes, it still iterates.

Comment: `var result = category_names_array[0].count + category_names_array[1].count + category_names_array[2].count;` this is without iterating, but I don't think you want to do that...

Comment: I see people giving answers but the question makes no sense at all. "add the number values" + "on the count property" [but count property has a value of type number already] +"of all items"+ "together" [say what?] + "and store in a variable" [in where? come again!] + "as a total count" [of what?! ] +"without iterating...

Please write the desired result. It's 1000 times easier

Comment: @BekimBacaj desired result = `var total_count = 69;`

Comment: Please edit your question to say "without iterating over the array **yourself**" (assuming that's what you mean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is uclear what did you mean by iterating. You must access all indexes of an array to do that. If you just want to avoid `for` loop, then use `Array.prototype.reduce` function.

```
var total = category_names_array.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + b.count;
}, 0);
```

If we define iterating as ordered accesing of array's indexes, then we must iterate over the array if we want to process all its indexes. Even stringifying object using JSON and then filtering and evaluating string is still iterating - JSON must iterate over the array to stringify it. Whatever you do, you must iterate over array's indexes to process it. Note that even adding two integers is some kind of iterating - you iterate over their bits to add them together.

Comment: No, adding two integers is **not** a kind of iteration. In most machine architectures, it's a single instruction.

Comment: @torazaburo. It depends on how you define iteration. If you have a function which will sum all values from array and you call that function, it it iterating? I assumed that OP asks for no iterating at all, even not on single instruction level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
sum(counts(array))
```

My, how very readable that is. But ooops, now we need to write `counts`. The easiest way is

```
function counts(array) { return array.map(elt => elt.count); }
```

Does `map` constitute "iteration"? Depends on your definition. Let's say no, since the iteration is happening inside the engine!!

All that remains is to write `sum`. We'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: all iterations happen inside the engine

Comment: To state the obvious, I am drawing a distinction between iterations written out in JavaScript, and those implicit in certain APIs (and carried out in the internal, C++ implementation of those APIs), although then again, who really cares?

Comment: Yes, but that's - nevertheless - an iterator no mater where you write it, a well written code gets precompiled anyway. You can however write a function object to which you assign the data to be processed and make use of it as plain as: `total_count = category_names_array; total_count >> 69`. But that's like going green using electric cars. "Who cares", for as long as the same (+entropy) amounts of fossil fuels are being burnt far away from our noses and eyesight?!
p.s.: I didn't down-vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive approach

```js
function sum(a, s) {
    s = s || 0;
    a = a.slice();
    return a.length ? sum(a, s + a.pop().count) : s;
}

var category_names_array = [{ name: 'cat1', count: 13 }, { name: 'cat2', count: 23 }, { name: 'cat3', count: 33 }];

console.log(sum(category_names_array));
```

ES6

```js
function sum(a) {
    var f = (a, ...r) => (s += a.count, r.length && f(...r)),
        s = 0;
    f(...a);
    return s;
}

var category_names_array = [{ name: 'cat1', count: 13 }, { name: 'cat2', count: 23 }, { name: 'cat3', count: 33 }];

console.log(sum(category_names_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve what you ask without ***iterating over the array***.

What you want to achieve is a **reduce** operation which in my opinion is a linear time algorithm. i.e it is guranteed to iterate through every element in the JS array.

An sample solution using Lodash JS

```js
var category_names_array = [
  {name: 'cat1', count: 13},
  {name: 'cat2', count: 23},
  {name: 'cat3', count: 33}
];

 var total = _.reduce(category_names_array, function(totalCount,item) {
  return totalCount + item.count;
},0);
```

Complexity O(n)